# android long forms always opens and focuses on the center of the form

Tags: android

I have developed an application where the form is very long and it scrolls to  2 pages.
 I have multiple doubts 
1) whenever my app starts it always goes to the center of the form instead of going to the top of the form,
2) whenever i do a drop down selection the  the form again scrolls  to the center automatically,
3)whenever i click my custom button in the form to take photo and after taking the photo,form again scrolls  to the center automatically,

how to avoid this scrolling and make my form stagnant where i am doing the entry .

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the focus on the first element when the form screen is shown first. For more info, check out [requestFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)
2. Use the next and previous identifiers so that the next element automatically takes focus when you are moving forward or backward on the form. For more info, check out [Focus Handling](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)
3. Same as point 2. When you set which item has to take focus next, that will prevent some central element taking focus.